# Order by sum column in with function

Tags: laravel

This is my code:

```
Producer::with(['orderItems' => function ($query) {
            $query->groupBy('branches.producer_id')->selectRaw("SUM(price) as price , branches.producer_id");
        }])->orderBy('price','ASC')->limit(5)->get();
```

But it con not see the price in ordering, how can i make it see the price column ?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please elaborate little more & provide input & expected output.

Comment: Add how you are looping through the results to access the product. it should be something like $producer->orderItems[0]->price

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```php
Producer::with(['orderItems' => function ($query) {
            $query->selectRaw("SUM(price) as price , branches.producer_id")->groupBy('branches.producer_id')->orderBy('price','ASC');
        }])->limit(5)->get();
```